# JavaScript Changing HTML's CSS Attributes in the 'onmouseover' event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I need to change the border color of my HTML `<li>` element when the user takes the cursor over the item and also to change the cursor icon when the mouse is over the item. I tried this, but it says "syntax error"

**HTML**

```
<li class="post-item-parent-div" onmouseover="onItemHover(this)" >
    <!-- More HTML Code -->
</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
function onItemHover(x) {

    x.border-top = "12px solid #0084FD";
    x.border-left = "12px solid #0084FD";
    x.cursor = "pointer";
}
```

I'm very new to JavaScript, so please help out :)

Comment: Guys I need the Javascript since I need to call other functions through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the css property names like below, as the style names with `-` can't be directly used in javascript.

See [CSS Properties Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference) for the reference names of css properties in javacsript

```js
function onItemHover(x) {
  x.style.borderTop = "12px solid #0084FD";
  x.style.borderLeft = "12px solid #0084FD";
  x.style.cursor = "pointer";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="post-item-parent-div" onmouseover="onItemHover(this)">
    some code
  </li>


</ul>
```

---

But also note that the [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) event will get triggered when you move to another element within the same parent `li`, so you might consider using the [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) event

```js
function onItemHover(x) {
  snippet.log('on over')
}

function onEnter(x) {
  snippet.log('on enter');
  
  x.style.borderTop = "12px solid #0084FD";
  x.style.borderLeft = "12px solid #0084FD";
  x.style.cursor = "pointer";
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="post-item-parent-div" onmouseover="onItemHover(this)" onmouseenter="onEnter(this)">
    some code <span>in span</span>  <a href="#">in link</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I think you miss the `style` after the `x`?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the `:hover` selector?

```
li.post-item-parent-div:hover
{
    border-top: 12px solid #0084FD;
    border-left: 12px solid #0084FD;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/zt66jf39/

Comment: Yes, you'll either need to create a new `.css` file and reference it, or add it in the `<head>` of the page.

Comment: No I need the Javascript since I need to call other functions through it

Comment: You should probably specify what other functions you want to call, especially since your question title is **changing CSS attributes...**

Comment: I've specified that it's a Javascript 'onmouseevent' in the tite :)

Comment: @Earthling : I respect your requirement. However, this is the most elegant way of achieving what you're trying to do. There are certain standards and ethos while you write programs. In case of HTML/CSS/JavaScript, HTML should only contain the markup. CSS should be used to define look and feel and JavaScript is where your logic goes into.

Comment: Further more, you should move your `mouseover` event assignment to javascript file and use functions like `addEventListener` (or `.on()` in case of jQuery) key your code clean and thus save unnecessary future efforts when it comes to maintaining the code.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
function onItemHover(x) {
   x.setAttribute("style", "border-top: 12px solid #0084FD; border-left: 12px solid #0084FD;cursor:pointer;");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code

```
    var item = document.getElementById("button");
item.addEventListener("mouseover", func, false);
item.addEventListener("mouseout", func1, false);

function func()
{  // not needed since item is already global, 
   // I am assuming this is here just because it's sample code?
   // var item = document.getElementById("button"); 
   item.setAttribute("style", "background-color:blue;")
}

function func1()
{  
   item.setAttribute("style", "background-color:green;")
}
```